# Can anyone else learn Drow Sign Language?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, languages

Can anyone else than drow learn Drow Sign Language? or is it a language that only drow can  learn because of, I dunno... dexterity or some other physical conditions?

Comment: If you're not a drow we can't answer

Comment: Given that Drow are, physiologically speaking, elves, it'd be weird if elves, at least, couldn't learn it.

Comment: While it is not a rules as written answer, there Neverwinter series of novels has both a human who is fluent in Drow sign language and a surface elf who has a minor understanding of it, so it seems perfectly possible lore-wise.

Comment: The first rule of drow sign language is you don't sign about drow sign language.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, RAW others can learn.

> Drow Sign Language is a bonus language for drow; others have to spend skill points to learn it. It has no alphabet or written form. (FRCS, p. 13)

As always DMs can rule however they want and may require you to find a willing drow to teach you. (If I allowed it, I would require this.)

Comment: Thanks for editing,  I'm on phone and its hard to do. Esp with spellchecker "corrections"

Comment: Drow of the Underdark states that DSL does have a written form, and that Dancing Lights can be used for Morse Code-like transmission of messages over long distances using DSL.  It also offers additional benefits to identifying spells with Somatic components, and sending secret messages.

Comment: Interesting caveat/exception. In that case, if your playing in FR, the FRCS book takes precedence, otherwise it'd seem fair to rule with the DotU

Comment: Except DotU has a great deal of FR specific information as well.  Since the FRCS is 3.0, wouldn't the 3.5 book take precedence?

Comment: @Scrollreader This issue is whether the *FRCS* is considered by the DM  a [primary source](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610).