# Where are the rules about what sources are primary?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Maybe it's just too early in the morning and my brain does not properly connect with the rest of the body, but...

## ...yes, this is a question about primary sources.

What happened is I was talking with some guys I know and we were talking about different versions of the same things in different books, when I mentioned *that usual thing* about primary sources taking precedence over later publications.
Someone asked me where these things were written so I opened an errata file or two - PHB and DMG namely - and... those rules I wanted to find aren't there, where I expected them to be, at all.

Quoting from those errata:

> When you find a disagreement between two D&D® rules sources, unless an official errata file says otherwise, the primary source is correct.

Ok, *this* I expected. Primary sources are correct. Right. But that's only half of what I needed to support my claim.
I keep reading on, skimming over the part where it talks about tables and text and then there's the definition of what constitutes a primary source. *Sorta.*
PHB is primary for something. DMG is primary for other things. MM is primary for some other. But I see nothing about precedence between, say, MM2 (with 3.5e upgrade) and Stormwrack.

What I expected to find was some text on the lines of "a book printed earlier is considered a primary source, unless the one printed later says otherwise". I *know* something like that exists, because I trust people who have been telling me so for ages, both here on this site and somewhere else. I even thing I saw it once on the books but...

**...where?**

Comment: To clarify, your asking which secondary books take precedence over other secondary books right?...ie a conflict between say Complete Adventurer & Complete Warrior?

Comment: @Ben-Jamin Close. He's asking for the definition of the hierarchy, not the actual hierarchy order, but the criteria which determine that order.

Comment: [Related] [Does the Rules Compendium overrule the core books?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/does-the-rules-compendium-overrule-the-core-books)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Primary Sources

The following text is at the beginning of each errata file. (This one from the [*Player's Handbook* errata](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata).)

> #### Errata Rule: Primary Sources
>
> When you find a disagreement between two... rules sources, unless an official errata file says otherwise, the primary source is correct. One example of a primary/secondary source is text taking precedence over a table entry. An individual spell description takes precedence when the short description in the beginning of the spells chapter disagrees.
>
> Another example of primary vs. secondary sources involves book and topic precedence. The *Player's Handbook*, for example, gives all the rules for playing the game, for playing PC races, and for using base class descriptions. If you find something on one of those
> topics from the *Dungeon Master's Guide* or the *Monster Manual* that disagrees with the *Player's Handbook*, you should assume the *Player's Handbook* is the primary source. The *Dungeon Master's Guide* is the primary source for topics such as magic item descriptions, special material construction rules, and so on. The *Monster Manual* is the primary source for monster descriptions, templates, and supernatural, extraordinary, and spell-like abilities.

Many read this as saying that *other* texts are primary sources—for example, the [*Expanded Psionics Handbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786933011) as the primary source for psionics (replacing the earlier edition's [*Psionics Handbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786918357) as the primary source for psionics) and [*Tome of Battle: The Book of 9 Swords*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786939222) as the primary source for martial adepts and martial disciplines—, but the Errata Rule mentions no **texts** beyond the *Player's Handbook*, *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and *Monster Manual*. DMs must decide which sources beyond these (if any) are the primary sources for their campaigns.

But, clearly, the three core books take precedence over everything each covers, including the *Player's Handbook*'s exceedingly broad mandate to cover "rules for playing the game" (whatever *that* means). (Note that the *Player's Handbook* and *Dungeon Master's Guide* are given non-exhaustive lists, but the *Monster Manual* is given what's apparently an *exhaustive* list, taking precedence *only* with regards those items. This is weird and probably not a huge source of worry to *anyone* unless one's going to [gamer court](https://web.archive.org/web/20200218130120/http://www.kodtweb.com:80/2012/03/08/gamer-court-cont-3/).)

## Secondary Sources

In one question, the [*D&D Frequently Asked Questions, Version 3.5*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910020605/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/faq) (last updated June 30, 2008) answers *not* an actual rules question but a *publication* question. That question is reproduced below:

> **Both [*Complete Arcane*] and [*Player's Guide to Faerûn*] include a feat named Innate Spell, but the prerequisites and uses per day differ. Which version is correct?**
>
> Unless stated otherwise, any time that a rule appears in two different sourcebooks (other than the *PH*, *DMG*, and *MM*), the most current sourcebook is considered correct and all previous sources are superseded. A book’s credits page lists its publication date (typically near the bottom of the page).
>
> In this case, [*Complete Arcane*] (published in November 2004) supersedes [*Player's Guide to Faerûn*] (published in March 2004), and thus its version of Innate Spell should be considered the official version. (41-2)

I can't find another reference for this oft-quoted meta-rule.

In rare cases, this creates confusion. For example, the armor special ability *fearsome* that originally appeared in the *Magic Item Compendium* (Mar. 2007) was superseded by the much better armor special ability of the same name in *Drow of the Underdark* (May 2007) then was superseded again by the original version in the *Magic Item Compendium* (July 2013).<sup>1</sup>

**Warning:** There are Internet places where bringing the *Main FAQ* into a discussion gets one mocked, shouted down, and accused of witchcraft. It is cited here *only* out of necessity, and I will happily edit this answer to reflect rules provided by a more well-regarded source if one can be found.

---

1. Which version of the armor special ability *fearsome* should be used in the campaign? Whatever the DM decides. This DM allows the version from *Drow of the Underdark*.

Comment: @KRyan Thank you, as that's *explicitly* the inference I mention, *explicitly* why I say *only* that no other texts are *mentioned*, and why I did *not* say that the inference was somehow mistaken. I was trying very carefully to raise points not dig in.

Comment: There **is no implication** that the core books are the **only** primary sources. The language in the errata rule is very explicit that those three books are the primary source on the listed things, but it literally uses “for example” – thus the implication you draw is *explicitly* contradicted by the errata rule. Thus your footnote 1 is incorrect, and rather than “reinforcing” the errata rule, the FAQ is *contradicting* it.

Comment: @KRyan Although I disagree, I am comfortable making this answer even neutraler. But just so I know more: What rules changes occur when primary sources beyond the core rules are in effect? That is, what rules argument is *won* when a reasonable text's considered a primary source and *lost* when a it's a secondary source?

Comment: @HeyICanChan In my 3.0 group we had a debate whether the new polymorph spell (Tome and Blood) was to take precedence over the core version (complicated by the fact that we only used core for that campaign). Which monster abilities are gainable from shapechange was the 3.5e problem (does Frostburn take precedence over MM2 3.5e upgrade?)

Comment: Albeit incidentally this answer provides what I was looking for. That text was in the "Official FAQs" - which officiality we don't really talk about, save the fact that those guys I were talking with consider them valuable.

Comment: @Zachiel *Tome and Blood* actually says, "This version of the spell [*polymorph other*] is now official and supersedes
the version presented in the *Player’s Handbook*" (94-5), so while I guess that could *still* cause arguments, wow, those'd be some *serious* rules lawyers. By the way, the [*Player's Handbook* (2012)](http://www.amazon.com/Dungeons-Dragons-3-5-Players-Handbook/dp/0786962461) updates to current the rules for changing form *via* spells and even the special ability wild shape.

Comment: Yes, yes, that was tangential. We were mostly talking about why a book we weren't even using had to be used as errata, nerfing a character.

Comment: I believe that somewhere in the Magic Item Compendium(as well as the Spell Compendium) there is at least a paragraph stating that it constitutes official errata for magic items in particular. I will go look for this right now to be sure.

Comment: @Javelin Both the *Spell Compendium* (in Sources on page 4) and *Magic Item Compendium* (in You Changed My Magic Items! also page 4) say the changes the books make should be used, but I can find in neither a mention of being actual errata.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Me neither now that I looked at them. I think there is a strong hint though, that the compendiums are to be considered up-to-date.

Comment: Found it! The original source of the Secondary Sources rules is the *Dragon* #336 (Oct. 2005) Sage Advice column “Official Answers to Your Questions” (95).

Answer (score -3):

there aren't tertiary sources to consider, so your worry is unnecessary. the core rulebooks are primary sources, and supplements are secondary sources. some rules from supplements become errata'd in and the source it's found in counts as a primary source for that ruling in that case, but generally speaking you won't have much difficulty between supplements because they will likely both be secondary sources.

do situation occur *at all* in which one supplement counts as a primary source and another supplement counts as a secondary source? sure. but it's pretty rare. the only example I can think of is the introduction of Swift and Immediate Actions to the game. in other words, the source which first introduces a new game mechanic counts as the primary source for that rule over other sources that also make use of that mechanic. Action Points, Immediate Actions, so forthe. if two different sources have two different sets of rules for the same thing, the primary source is which ever source introduced that rule in the first place, unless there was an erratta rule change.

Comment: We were talking about different versions of monsters appearing on different manuals (that are not MM1). Anyway, I recall something about printed first = primary, which is wat I'm trying to find.

Comment: then my answer still stands. if the monster has multiple versions across different sources, the primary source is that which the monster was first introduced, unless there was an errata change. for example, Duergar use MM as a primary source, over the Expanded Psionics Handbook. the same rule applies with monsters who appear in multiple version but only in books other than MM1.