# Does ability damage benefit from bonuses to damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, optimization, damage, ability-scores

Do things that interact with damage also interact with ability damage?

For example, if you have an attack that deals ability damage, such as an arrow created with Shadow Arrow (Champions of Ruin, p. 34), can you apply a damage bonus, such as from a +4 strength composite bow, to the ability damage?

Reason: I'm making an archer that stacks ranged damage bonuses and I'm wondering if it is a good idea to pick up an ability damage spell to complement his build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 3.5, *Rules Compendium* addressed this, saying that when you have an attack that deals ability damage (or negative levels), and would receive a bonus to its damage, the bonus damage is dealt as negative energy-based HP damage, not additional ability damage or negative levels.

So, for example, if you have 3d6 sneak attack damage and sneak attack with *enervate*, you deal 1d4 negative levels + 3d6 negative energy damage.

Note that bonuses to *weapon* damage never apply to spells. So inspire courage (“a +1 morale bonus on [...] weapon damage rolls”) doesn’t apply, but weirdly Weapon Specialization *does* because it says that it applies a bonus to “damage of the chosen weapon” and we have a special ruling saying that spells can be chosen as the “weapon”—if it said “weapon damage” of the chosen weapon, we might have a problem.

In researching this question for Pathfinder, I find a lot of people saying the same thing, but I cannot find any statements in the Pathfinder rules that indicate it. It seems that this is a rule that the Pathfinder community has ported (consciously or not) from 3.5 without Paizo’s assistance.

Comment: Could you cite the first paragraph? I couldn't find anything that led me to believe, for example, a [lamia](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersKtoL.html#lamia) ranger with the special ability favored enemy (humans +2) deals Regdar 1d4 points of wisdom drain and 2 points of negative energy damage with a a successful wisdom drain attack.

Comment: The section in RC that states that extra negative levels and ability damage from spells becomes negative energy damage seems to be specific to Precision damage: "unless that spell deals ability damage or ability drain, or it bestows negative levels. Spells that fall into these categories instead deal extra hit point damage in the form of negative energy." (RC, P136) I find no other reference to either negative levels or ability damage (or drain) being treated differently to other forms of damage (nonlethal, lethal); what you refer to looks like a specific rule for spells and Precision damage.

Answer (score 1):

Both games often fail to make distinctions between *lethal* damage and other kinds of damage, the games assuming the reader just somehow *knows*. But, fortunately, lethal damage *is* the most common kind of damage, so it's safest for the reader to assume that when an effect says it deals *damage* or adds to *damage*, the effect means it deals or adds to *lethal* damage. Anyway, here's a little help.

## The *Rules Compendium* for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* offers some insight…

First, the *Rules Compendium* says, "Any spell that requires an attack roll is weaponlike" (132). Then it continues, saying

> Weaponlike spells that deal some form of damage—lethal damage, nonlethal damage, ability damage, or ability drain—or that bestow negative levels can threaten critical hits, can be used with precision damage…, and can be used with favored enemy damage bonuses.<sup>1</sup> **Since a weaponlike spell isn’t actually a weapon, Strength modifiers on damage rolls and magical effects that increase weapon damage don’t increase damage from a weaponlike spell unless the spell’s description says otherwise.** (136)

(Emphasis mine.) This means, for example, the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*chill touch*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsC.html#chill-touch) [necro] (*PH* 209) typically threatens a critical hit on a natural 20 and, if confirmed, deals 2d6 points of damage, and, if the defender fails the Fortitude saving throw, the defender's dealt 2 points of Strength damage. Also, for example, this means a rogue/wizard that successfully hits a typical flat-footed foe with the ray created by the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*enervation*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#enervation) [necro] (*PH* 226), in addition to bestowing the negative levels, the rogue/wizard deals his sneak attack damage as negative energy damage (see *Rules Compendium* 136). But even if the mighty wizard has Strength 18, he still only deals 1d6 points of electricity damage per caster level (maximum 5d6) with the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*shocking grasp*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsS.html#shocking-grasp) [evoc] (*PH* 279) unless using an unarmed unarmed strike to deliver what's normally a touch attack (*PH* 141-2).

### …But the spell *shadow arrow* is complicated

Then there's the weird corner case of the 4th-level ranger spell *shadow arrow* [necro] (*Champions of Ruin* 34). The spell *shadow arrow*, on its surface, doesn't *seem* like a weaponlike spell. Its target entry is a masterwork arrow or a masterwork bolt, for instance, not a creature, but the spell's description *does* say, in part, that

> **Make a ranged touch attack with the missile instead of a normal ranged attack. Instead of dealing normal damage, a shadow arrow deals 1d6 points of Strength damage.** The arrow or bolt must be fired during the same round the spell is cast, or the magic dissipates and is lost. The projectile is destroyed even if it misses its target. (*Champions of Ruin* 34)

(Emphasis mine.) This DM would rule that since there's no *other* way to use the spell's effect *except* by making with it an attack roll, the spell *is*, in fact, a weaponlike spell and follows the rules above, including no Strength modifiers on the (ability) damage roll and, for example, no increase in the (ability) damage from magical effects due to the weapon firing it nor spells cast on it.

The alternative to this is, perhaps, a reading like *It creates a magic arrow that's fired and that means the spell itself is not weaponlike; the arrow's just ammunition fired from a weapon* and *'Instead of dealing normal damage' means instead of the arrow dealing normal arrow damage not instead of the attack dealing normal damage!* If the DM agrees then doesn't immediately ban the spell, the DM may allow *any* damage modifiers that would apply to a *normal* arrow's damage to apply to the *shadow arrow*'s ability damage. Doing so would trivialize many encounters and probably relegate the spell to the too-dangerous-to-use pile (because if the PCs use it, the antagonists will, too).

(An example: A level 9 mystic ranger on round 1 casts the 1st-level ranger spell *hunter's mercy* [div] (*SpC* 117) followed by the 1st-level ranger spell *hunter's eye* [div] (*PH2* 114-5) modified to a 2nd-level spell by the feat Extend Spell, and, on round 2, casts *shadow arrow*. A successful ranged touch attack with that one *shadow arrow* deals an impressive 5d6 points of Strength damage. There's no saving throw, and [Strength 0 means the creature's helpless](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/abilitiesAndConditions.html#ability-damaged).)

#### By the way, monsters don't usually add ability score modifiers to ability damage they deal

Most PCs don't get the opportunity to deal ability damage except as a consequence of other attacks (like the aforementioned *chill touch* or by employing poison), so, I guess, broadly, this whole issue *can* be argued, but a quick search of the *Monster Manual* creatures that deal ability damage or ability drain directly as an attack—like the [allip](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersA.html#allip)'s and the [lamia](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersKtoL.html#lamia)'s wisdom drains, the [green hag](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersHtoI.html#green-hag)'s and the roper's weakness, and the [shadow](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersS.html#shadow)'s strength damage—none of whom get any of *their* ability modifiers added to the ability damage or ability drain *they* inflict—leads me to believe spells and other effects that *grant* a creature the ability to deal ability damage or ability drain *also* shouldn't get an ability modifier to that damage unless they say so explicitly, and the spell *shadow arrow* doesn't say that.

## In *Pathfinder* this is less clear

As of this writing *Pathfinder* has made no official pronouncements on the interactions between unusual kinds damage like ability damage, ability drain, and the bestowing of negative levels. Probably the closest a reader can get is this exchange from [the *Pathfinder Core Rulebook* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nef):

> #### Question
>
> Can you take [Weapon Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-specialization-combat---final) (ray) or [Improved Critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat-) (ray) as feats? How about Weapon Specialization (bomb) or Improved Critical (bomb)?
>
> #### Answer
>
> All four of those are valid choices.
>
> Note that Weapon Specialization (ray) only adds to hit point damage caused by a ray attack that would normally deal hit point damage; it doesn't increase ability score damage or drain (such as the Dexterity drain from [*polar ray*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polar-ray)), penalties to ability scores (such as from [*ray of enfeeblement*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/ray-of-enfeeblement)) or drain, negative levels (such as from [*enervation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation)), or other damage or penalties from rays.

This *could* imply that *Pathfinder* limits damage bonuses to effects dealing lethal damage… except that the *D&D 3.5* feat Ranged Spell Specialization (*Complete Arcane* 82) *also* limits itself to affecting spells dealing lethal damage *and* that this *FAQ* entry uses the same odd phrasing as that feat (*hit point damage* rather than *lethal damage* or even just *damage*), evidence of, perhaps, the *FAQ* having borrowed rules from *Complete Arcane*. So before accepting that this *FAQ* entry *Pathfinder* limits damage bonuses in such a way, keep in mind that *Complete Arcane* clarified for *3.5* the idea that, for example, a rogue can deal sneak attack damage with the spell *enervation*!

Really, since the *3.5* rules are clear enough and the *Pathfinder* rules aren't, I suggest using the *3.5* rules until *Pathfinder* decides to rule formally on the subject.

(For further comparison, you can check out the *Pathfinder* versions of the
[allip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/allip), [green hag](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/hag/hag-green), [lamia](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/lamia), [roper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/roper), and [shadow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/shadow). None of them add ability scores to their ability damage or ability drain attacks either.)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The inclusion here of *favored enemy damage* is possibly from the *Rules Compendium* believing that the favored enemy damage bonus is extra precision damage (as it was prior to the *3.5* revision) rather than a flat damage bonus. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70662/8610).) This is the *Rules Compendium*'s sole mention of favored enemy.