# Do multiclassing rogues need the Craven feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, multi-classing, sneak-attack

I've always been under the impression is that if you multiclass out of the rogue class into a class that doesn't progress sneak attack, you need to take the Craven feat if you want it to be at all relevant. But now I'm debating whether or not this is true. Does a multiclass character need Craven for sneak attack to be effective or no? By that I mean does a character need their sneak attack damage to be particularly high for it to be effective? And If not then how would such a character stealth take down someone? Should such a situation arise?

Comment: Define "effective?"  Obviously if you want it to advance, yes.  If you want it to be a large part of your damage output, depends what you're multiclassing into.  What makes it more critical when multiclassing than just pumping up the damage when single-classed? I'm not sure how this can be answered objectively in its current form.

Comment: Alternatively, changing it to be a more general question about the pros and cons of the Craven feat would probably be acceptable (certainly is answerable; see my answer). Then it becomes less of an objective question and more of a (hopefully good) subjective question.

Answer (score 2):

Craven is a great damage boost to a sneak attacker, *especially* one that is behind a single-classed rogue in sneak attack damage dice. A single-classed rogue expects approximately 1¾ damage/level from sneak attack. Craven boosts that to 2¾, which is +60% damage, and it scales on character level, so the boost is easily double or more for a multiclassed rogue (in the extreme case, 1d6 sneak attack damage, the boost is nearly 6×).

Certainly, 1d6 damage is not significant at 20th level (or indeed, at many levels prior to that point), while 1d6+20 damage is (or at least is more so, as long as you’re making enough attacks). But context is crucial here: how much damage are you doing otherwise? How many attacks are you making?

If you were a charger without pounce, but with Shock Trooper, Spirited Charge, a lance, *et al.*, you could easily have a single attack dealing upwards of +100 damage at 20th level. Is another +20 on top of that, that also requires you to awkwardly ensure your charge target is eligible for sneak attack, going to make a big difference? No, it is not.

On the other hand, if your build is a hodgepodge of things that gets fifteen attacks, adding +20 to each of them is a big deal, especially since you probably haven’t otherwise scored a lot of damage bonuses in your devotion to simply having more attacks.

Generally speaking, sneak attack is an awkward and difficult form of damage-dealing. Setting it up is difficult and capitalizing on it is arguably more so. That takes a lot of investment, and Craven alone isn’t going to save things if you aren’t in a position to make the most of sneak attack to begin with. And even with that investment, you won’t keep up with dedicated two-handed weapon damage dealers.

Finally, this all assuming we are talking solely about damage. Rogues, particularly multiclass ones, may not care about damage in combat. They may be social characters, mostly ignoring combat, or they may focus on battlefield control or debuffs, or what have you. For such rogues, sneak attack is an incidental feature that doesn’t matter much (and should maybe be replaced with [feats](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#rogue)).

The last thing to consider is that, in addition to the difficulties that sneak attack itself has, Craven adds a **massive** drawback—you lose the feat if you are immune to fear. Which also means you lose the feat if you are immune to mind-affecting. And since these immunities are extremely valuable, almost critical, at mid-to-high levels, giving up on them is a really big deal. That alone is a really good reason to question the need to take Craven.

But in the end, if you have your heart set on dealing damage specifically via sneak attack, Craven is too large a damage booster to ignore.

Comment: So it really comes down to do i wish to be relevent in terms of damage or Battlefield control...what about stealth takedowns? While I know that's rare there may come a time when a character would need that. Edited question for relevence.

Comment: @Masakan What does “stealth takedown” mean to you? Do you mean going off solo, sneaking, and then expecting to kill a guard or something in one blow so as to eliminate any chance of an alarm being sounded? *Good luck.* D&D is not a game designed for that kind of thing, really, and unless you’re quite a few levels higher than the target, it’s rather difficult to ensure it will happen—and sneak attack isn’t the way to go about it since it relies so much on multiple attacks. Your best bet is, as usual, magic, e.g. *silence* or something.

Comment: You would think an ability called SNEAK attack would be useful for that sort of thing...but if not then...well dang. So its literally only good for extra damage in the thick of combat while getting the jump on people. geez.

Comment: @Masakan Can I interest you, sir, in the special ability [death attack](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/assassin.html#assassin-death-attack)?

Answer (score 1):

## Many mundane warriors will probably *want* Craven

The benefit of the feat Craven says, "You take a −2 penalty on saving throws against fear effects. However, when making a sneak attack, you deal an extra 1 point of damage per character level" (*Champions of Ruin* 17). Further, the Craven feat's prerequisites are light, necessitating *only* sneak attack—*not* specifying a minimum number of dice!—and *lacking* an immunity to fear.

So in exchange for not gaining immunity to fear effects (the feat's benefit is lost if the creature consumes a [*heroes' feast*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsHtoL.html#heroes-feast) (*PH* 240), for instance), the creature, when it would deal sneak attack damage, also deals an extra 1 point of weapon damage per character level (plus, because this is *not* extra damage *dice*, such damage is multiplied on critical hits).<sup>1</sup> This is an *incredible* boon, making the feat Craven at character level 2 or higher, for example, better—if more tactically difficult to use—than the feat [Weapon Specialization](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#weapon-specialization) (*PH* 102), despite that feat being needlessly trapped behind 4 levels of fighter. (That the feat Weapon Specialization is itself a *bad feat* is a topic for another question. (*Hint:* It *is* bad!)) The Craven feat's prerequisites even make it a somewhat competitive and drawback-free low-Strength alternative to the feat [Power Attack](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#power-attack) (*PH* 98) (for 1-handed weapon users, anyway), and nothing stops a creature that takes each feat from *simultaneously* benefiting from *both!*

However, as per [KRyan's fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/94790/8610), a mundane warrior may not need nor even *want* the feat Craven if the warrior, for example, is already dealing enough damage *or* has [other priorities](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45581/8610) *or* would see his build's momentum wrecked by taking even 1 level of a class that grants sneak attack. (Most typical casters, on the other hand, will usually find other feats more useful, but even a caster may find the feat Craven useful if, for example, taking levels in a prestige class like arcane trickster (*DMG* 177-8), spellwarp sniper (*Complete Scoundrel* 64-7), or unseen seer (*Complete Mage* 81-4).)

Also, an adventurer's vulnerability to fear effects *can* mean the adventurer's death. ([Ernir](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/5901/ernir)'s awesome (if just a *little* outdated) post ["Lists of Necessary Magic Items"](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items) on the *Giant in the Playground* forums puts Fear Immunity at #5 of 13, for example.) In addition to fleeing the encounter, an adventurer that's [panicked](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_panicked&alpha=P) (and, if using instead of the *DMG* on Fear (294) the *Rules Compendium* on Fear (53), maybe [cowering](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_cowering&alpha=C)) *drops what he's holding*, and, at the *very* least, at high levels, such items can be *very* expensive to replace!

In short, *yes*, a high-level creature that possesses only 1d6 or so dice of sneak attack damage and that's *not* also making a dozen vicious and crippling attacks each turn *and* that wants having *Sneak Attack +1d6* or whatever written on his character sheet to matter *will* find that the feat Craven accomplishes the goal of making it worthwhile to continue to try to get in position to deal sneak attack damage. However, whether the [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost) of the feat Craven is low, fair, or simply too high will depend mightily on the campaign.

### [Stealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_game) [takedowns and such](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BackStab) in [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e)

This player has always imagined stealth takedowns as the product of the creature having successfully used against a foe the extraordinary ability [death attack](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/assassin.html#assassin-death-attack), the signature ability of the prestige class [assassin](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/assassin.html#_top), but available *via* several prestige classes, even including [evil-is-not-mandatory prestige classes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94794/8610).

However, with some GM adjudication, it may be easier than that. The *Rules Compendium* on Helpless Defenders says that a creature that is "paralyzed, [magically] *held*, bound, sleeping, [or] unconscious" is a helpless defender but adds that a helpless defender also includes any creature "otherwise completely at your mercy" (62). A DM may rule that when a creature's adjacent to a foe *and* the creature remains completely undetected by the foe *and* the foe has *zero* reasons to suspect *any* threats that such a foe is helpless. In such a case, the creature can take a full-round action to [*coup de grace*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_coupdegrace&alpha=C) the hard-working-yet-tragically-unaware 2-sp-a-day guard.<sup>3</sup> (Exercise discretion in attempts to persuade the DM into accepting this point of view; pervasive use of this rule may eventually backfire, rendering PCs equally vulnerable.<sup>4</sup>)

But, barring the ability death attack and a perhaps *too* liberal reading of the Helpless Defenders rules, a creature's ability to down silently from surprise a foe with a standard action is the province of unique magic items, special abilities, and powers, spells, soulmelds, utterances, and the like.<sup>5</sup>

#### Outside the standard rules, stealth takedowns are sometimes supported

For instance, the feat Strike the Innocent (the licensed-by-Wizards-of-the-Coast and [well-reviewed](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/classic/rev_7962.phtml)-although-I-found-it-wanting [*Villain Design Handbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594590109) 62) allows a creature to take a full-round action to make a *coup de grace* against any foe—helpless or not—that possesses a base attack bonus of exactly +0. The feat Lockdown (the Wizards-of-the-Coast-approved yet fan-created [*Planescape Campaign Setting*](http://mimir.planewalker.com/sections/30-35-pscs) Chapter 4: Skills and Feats 53) allows a creature that's grappling a foe to make an opposed grapple check to either damage the foe or pin the foe. Success means that, instead of the damage or the pin, the foe's bound; a bound creature is helpless. Other, easier and elegant silent takedown methods undoubtedly exist in the countless multitude of third-party d20 System products.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The *Rules Compendium* says, "Sometimes damage is multiplied, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage dice *and add all modifiers* multiple times. Total the results. Extra damage *dice* over and above a weapon’s normal damage… are never multiplied" (17; emphasis mine). Thus, like the bonus on damage rolls that gained from the special ability [favored enemy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70662/8610), the damage dealt due to the feat Craven is added *and multiplied* on a critical hit.
<sup>**2**</sup> *War Story:* In one of my campaigns a PC took 19 levels in a homebrew class that granted sneak attack also found that the class at that level had a special ability like the spell [*mind blank*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsMtoO.html#mind-blank) except that the PC could at will take a free action to activate or deactivate the effect. The PC took the feat Craven, and the player had to declare *It's off* when the PC made his attacks and *It's on* when the PC finished… and the player would occasionally forget to do one, the other, or both. That is, even with an ability as powerful and *seemingly* convenient as this, the feat Craven intruded on the player's playspace and sometimes left the PC vulnerable when he ought not to've been.
<sup>**3**</sup> Even so, this isn't easy. Without, for example, the feat Death Blow (*Complete Adventurer* 106) or a similar effect, the typical creature must, during the surprise round, [start a full-round action](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/actionsInCombat.html#start-complete-full-round-action)—the *coup de grace*—and *finish* that full-round action on his initiative count during the first regular round of combat! Alternatively, the creature during the surprise round *does nothing*, remains undetected, and (*ahem*) executes the *coup de grace* during his first regular whole turn. Either way, a gamble.
<sup>**4**</sup> For comparison, in Crafty Games's d20 System RPG [*Spycraft 2.0*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594720371), when an agent finds himself in "appalling peril" it's a Terminal Situation:

> Outside combat only, the [GM] may declare that any situation from which a character cannot logically escape is a Terminal Situation. Commonly, the victim must be helpless… for a Terminal Situation to apply. Until the situation abates, any of the victim’s opponents with line of sight to him may spend 1 action die to cause him to either fall unconscious or die…, as appropriate to the circumstances at hand. (*Spycraft Roleplaying Game, Version 2.0* 350)

Typically, in that game, the GM has from 6 to 10 action dice per session, but these are usually used to keep alive NPCs rather than to straight-up murder feckless PCs. More often, the PC has an opportunity to spend 1 of his 3 to 6 or so action dice per session to have an NPC that's in appalling peril just shut up and die already. It's not nearly as crazy (nor as adversarial!) as it sounds, and, although I've not tried it in *D&D 3.5e*, using for a similar purpose, for example, [action points](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/unearthedCombat.html#_top) instead of *Spycraft*'s action dice seems a reasonable house rule.
<sup>**5**</sup> A creature that can take a full-round action or more has it far easier, though, usually by (mundanely) dealing the foe large amounts of ability damage, often *via* poison but alternatives exist. For example, the feat Hamstring Attack (*Dragon* #313 30) allows, in certain circumstance, dealing 1d4 points of Dexterity damage per attack with a natural weapon, and the you're-never-going-to-take-it-because-it's-terrible feat Illithid Extraction (*Complete Psionic* 61) with vast effort under laboratory conditions allows dealing 2d4 points of Intelligence damage. A special shout-out to the feat Savvy Rogue (*Complete Scoundrel* 80-1) which allows the rogue special ability [crippling strike](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/rogue.html#rogue-crippling-strike) (*PH* 51) to deal Strength damage even to foes immune to sneak attack damage (but, sadly, *still* not to foes immune to ability damage).

Answer (score 0):

> I've always been under the impression is that if you multiclass out of the rogue class into a class that doesn't progress sneak attack, you need to take the Craven feat if you want it to be at all relevant. But now I'm debating whether or not this is true. Does a multiclass character need Craven for sneak attack to be effective or no?

Of course it's not true. Sure, craven would give +1/level to sneak attack damage and that's nice. Hell, it's nice even for straight rogues - but for any character it's not great. I'd only take it if I did not have something else I was working towards, or if I was focusing on a character that was emphasizing sneak attacks. Depending on your playstyle, the group/DM you're with, and the campaign you're either using sneak attack a couple times a gaming session, or you're attacking with it more often than you're not. That would weigh heavily on whether or not craven is useful compared to other feats.

If you're stuck on craven being necessary then you're probably also focused on being able to disappear into the shadows, doing obscene damage while avoiding attention, and/or making sure you're always flanking the enemy. If that's the case, why multi-class at all? Rogues are the best at that. Maybe grab some sorcerer levels to augment your ability to remain unseen (or just get True Strike), but honestly, why do anything else? That said, if you're doing that, craven is a GREAT feat anyway because it's going to add +[insertyourlevelhere] damage once per round, which is hard to beat.

But if you're multi-classing into something more combat oriented, like a ranger, your full round attack will soon be doing enough damage that there are better things to spend your feats on than +somedamage to the first attack sometimes. If you're going to focus on being a magic user, sneak attack won't come in too handy unless you build your spell list around rays, etc.

TL;DR: Whether or not to take craven is personal and based on playstyle, but rogues are always awesome at multi-class because they get evasion.